# irobot_create_2_1 does not run

Tags: ros, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to run irobot_create_2_1 driver , i do rosmake successfully however i cannot run it. this is the error i am getting

rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/bin/driver.py", line 15, in 
from irobot_create_2_1.msg import SensorPacket
ImportError: No module named irobot_create_2_1.msg

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12378/irobot_create_2_1-does-not-run/) by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Other threads have brought to my attention that I accidentally pulled both the Makefile and rosdep.yaml from the irobot_create_2_1 repo when doing some other maintenance work.I believe this is your problem (and why the older package release solved it for winterhater). This has been corrected both in the repo and in our newer package releases (though these of course take time to catch up). In the meantime, you can pull a fresh copy from the repo:

```
svn co https://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/irobot_create_2_1 irobot_create_2_1
```

or you can download the individually missing files: [Makefile](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/irobot_create_2_1/Makefile) and [rosdep.yaml](http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/irobot_create_2_1/rosdep.yaml) .

My sincere apologies. This was really bone-headed and I will spend the requisite time on the wheel.

_Trevor

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2011-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1